# Multiple accounts in Thunderbird 10

Tags: thunderbird

I currently have 3 separate accounts in Thunderbird 10:

- for personal email
- for my home business
- for my outside employment

All 3 have different incoming email addresses. I want to set up another account for emails that relate to the listserv I administer; right now, those incoming emails just go into my personal account. When I attempt to set up a new POP3 account using my personal email address, however, I get a popup message that says, "Incoming server already exists."

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Is the email address for the new account the same as one that already exist (you said that you already have account for personal mail)? If so, you can't set 2 different accounts for the same email address. What you can do, though, is to to create a folder in Thunderbird for the mailing list and set a filter to put the mailing list messages in that folder. If the account that you are trying to set is different than the personal account that you have, the problem may be due to old deleted account with the same email address as the one that you are trying to set.